# How do you invoke the Visual Studio Preprocessor from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio, preprocessor

I want to implement the solution using the pre-processor described here:

[Reuse define statement from .h file in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100854/reuse-define-statement-from-h-file-in-c-code)

Bonus points if you can point me to the docs at MSDN.  I'm having trouble finding them...

Comment: I'm curious to see the answer to this one as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the /P option to cl.exe ... see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6(VS.80).aspx)