# how to read constants from .h file in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I want to read the constants in C#, these constants are defined in a .h file for C++. Can anyone tell me how to perform this in C# ? The C++ .h file looks like:

```
#define MYSTRING1 "6.9.24 (32 bit)"
#define MYSTRING2 "6.8.24 (32 bit)"
```

I want to read this in C# ?

Comment: You would need the open the file in a StreamReader and read each line.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100854/reuse-define-statement-from-h-file-in-c-code

Comment: No i do not want to read it line by line. i want to get all the constants that are defined in .h file in my C# variables.

Comment: Would a code that transforms the .h file into a C# class with public static properties like `MYSTRING1` be okay? Or could you specify exactly how do you want to use it? Preferably with some code samples. Also, are all of the constants strings?

Comment: in my .h file... there are constants and i want to read the specific one. i want to use some wrapper class that could do it for me but not know how to do that :) . i got the idea that wrapper classes can interact with the un-managed code but get the detail at all.

Comment: @AsadIqbal - What you want is C# to read your C file which is not possible unless you read the file using a stream.

Comment: @AsadIqbal, you want to read one of the constants from the file? Something like `wrapper.Get("MYSTRING1")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a really simple answer that you can use on each line of your .h file to extract the string value.

```
string GetConstVal(string line)
{
  string[] lineParts = string.Split(line, ' ');
  if (lineParts[0] == "#define")
  {
    return lineParts[2];
  }
  return null;
}
```

So any time it returns null, you don't have a constant.  Now keep in mind that it is only getting the value of the constant, not the name, but you can easily modify the code to return that as well via out parameter, etc.

If you want to represent other data types, like integers, etc. you will have to think of something clever since macros in C++ don't really count as type safe.

Comment: I read the constants that can be changed any time mean there name etc ... i want to get some specific constants only ... in your proposed solution if constant name changed then how it possible to get it ?

Comment: The code listed doesn't take the name into account at all.  Also, if you are looking for a specific constant and its name changes, there isn't anything that you can do.  Whichever human changes the name of the constant will also have to change what they are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1- Create a C++ wrapper code, which wraps these macros, export this code to a lib or dll and use it from C#.

2- read/parse the .h file from your code, and get the values at run-time.

Comment: Kindly tell me what is the purpose of this Wrapper class, how i use it and its functionality ? i am interested in this solution.

Comment: @AsadIqbal - You don't seem to have the knowlege required to do the first option do the second option.